# Intersection of plane with Segre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

$\newcommand{\complex}{\mathbb{C}}$ Let $Seg \subseteq \complex^M \otimes \complex^N$ be the set of elements of the form $v \otimes w$. It is well-known that a general linear subspace of dimension $(M-1)(N-1)$ intersects $Seg$ only in the point $\{0\}$, as this is the codimension of the algebraic variety $Seg$, and that every linear subspace of dimension $(M-1)(N-1)+1$ intersects $Seg$ at some non-zero point.

I would like to know if every linear subspace of dimension $(M-1)(N-1)+(M-1)$ contains in its intersection with $Seg$ a linear subspace of the form $H \otimes v$, where $H\subseteq \complex^M$ is a hyperplane and $v \in \complex^N$ is a non-zero vector.

More generally for any $k \in \{1,...,M-1\}$, does every linear subspace of dimension $(M-1)(N-1)+k$ contain in its intersection with $Seg$ a linear subspace of the form $H \otimes v$, where $H\subseteq \complex^M$ is a linear subspace of dimension $k$?

Comment: For $k \geq 2$, the answer is no. By Bertini  the intersection is smooth for a general linear space(say $L$). By Lefschetz (with $k \geq 2$), the intersection must be connected. Since it is smooth, it is irreducible. Hence we must have $Seg \cap L = v \otimes H$, scheme-theoretically. This is impossible for degree reasons.

Comment: PS: I translated everything in projective space.

Comment: @Libli Thank you!